# PostgreSQL CONVERT error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to sort by converted column, but psql returns error:

> SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CONVERT(col1 USING
>   utf8_to_iso_8859_2);
>
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING" LINE 1: SELECT * FROM
>   table ORDER BY CONVERT(col1 USING utf8...
>                                                             ^
>
> *** *Error* *****
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "USING" SQL state: 42601

I saw this function used liked this before and it's in documentation too, so I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are *mixing two features*. One is [**collation support**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html), that would make sense in an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col1 COLLATE "fr_FR";
```

The other one is the [`convert()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) that transcodes a string from a source encoding to a defined destination encoding:

```
SELECT convert('my_string', 'UTF8', 'ISO_8859_2')
```

But that has no effect on the sort order - except with locale `C` or a `bytea` column.

Comment: Thank you, ORDER BY COLLATE was exactly what I needed. I had to upgrade psql from 8.4 to 9.1, but fortunately it was quite easy.

Comment: @GvS: Cool! And v9.1 won't hurt, either. Lots of shiny new stuff. :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean to use:

```
CONVERT(col1, 'iso-8859-2')
```

to convert col1 (text) to iso-8859-2 (bytea), assuming your database is stored as utf-8. `convert`, `convert_to` and `convert_from` are showin in table 9-6 here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html